# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'pray.findIndex')]

Tags: javascript, react-native

when i run the code i get this error,

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'pray.findIndex')]

thx for help

```
const [pray, setPray] = useState([]);
const fetchPray = async county => {
  const url4 = '-' + county;
  console.log(url4);
  fetch(url4)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => setPray(json))
    .then(pray => {
      let index = pray.findIndex(d => d.MiladiTarihKisa === date);
      let selectData = pray[index];

      setVakitGunes(selectData.Gunes);
      setVakitImsak(selectData.Imsak);
      setVakitOgle(selectData.Ogle);
      setVakitIkindi(selectData.Ikindi);
      setVakitAksam(selectData.Aksam);
      setVakitYatsi(selectData.Yatsi);
      setGunTurkce(selectData.MiladiTarihUzun);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
    .finally(() => setLoading4(false));
};
```

Comment: What does `setPray()` return? The error indicates that it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Add the definition of `setPray` to the snippet.

Comment: i edit question can you check it?

Comment: setPray doesn't return anything so the value of `pray` will always be undefined in your last `promise.then` callback

Comment: @MrCodingB imsorry sir i didn't understand  , could u show it on the code. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The `useState` hook returns:

1. The state value (in your case `pray`)
2. The function to change that value (in your case `setPray`)

`setPray` can be given either a callback returning the new value for `pray` or just the new value for `pray` and returns `void`.

So in your code:

```js
const [pray, setPray] = useState([]);

...

    .then(json => setPray(json)) // 'setPray' returns void here
    .then(pray => {              // 'pray' is always undefined, since void isn't a value
        ...
    });
```

I don't know what exactly you want to achieve, but as far as I understood your code, just calling `setPray` inside the last `.then` call should fix it:

```js
const [pray, setPray] = useState([]);
const fetchPray = async county => {
  const url = '-' + county;

  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      setPray(json);
      const index = json.findIndex(d => d.MiladiTarihKisa === date);
      const selectData = json[index];

      ...
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
    .finally(() => setLoading4(false));
};
```

Comment: You should show how to fix it.

Comment: @Barmar yes,i didn't understand :/

Comment: @Barmar It's difficult to show how to fix "it", "it" isn't specified in the question. I don't know what the goal of the code is, so I can't tell OP how to change his code.

Comment: "it" is the error that results from `pray` being undefined in `pray.findIndex(...)`

Comment: Yes that much is apparent, but since I explained the cause of that error one should know how to fix "it"...I just can't tell OP how to fix "it" exactly, because I don't know the behavior he is trying to achieve. Since you seem to have understood OP's problem much better than I did, the more constructive way of contributing would be to answer the question yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Just a thought, what if you set the default state to an empty object instead of an array:

```
const [pray, setPray] = useState({});
```

If that doesn't work, can you provide the entire file or link to dig deeper? I also think @MrCodingB is on the right track... here is an example of using useState with the function (setCount in example, setPray for you) returning something (count + 1)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: They're not using that value of `pray` what was set from the call to `useState()`. It's being shadowed by the local variable in `.then(pray => ...)`

Comment: This doesn't really provide an explanation or solution. It seems more like a guess to a possible solution, which also wouldn't work.